# How do I check if a browser supports HTML5 and CSS3 features using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to make an if statement or a function in **ASP.NET MVC** project that checks to see if the client's browser support **HTML5 & CSS** or not.

Comment: [modernizr](https://modernizr.com) is what you want, thank me later

Comment: @RakibulIslam can you give some example code

Comment: You can check this [link](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#techniques)...quiet nice tutorial in this aspect